# Is there an event delegation in dart SDK?

Tags: dart

Imagine, you want to listen to all clicks made to any anchor element on page. The anchors on page can be dynamically added/removed during the page lifetime and you want to register all of the click events, even on newly added.

Is there any way how to attach delegated event (like in jQuery) in Dart using its standard libraries?

In jQuery you can achieve this with `element.on('click', '.selector', handler);`.

Comment: Sadly no, I've also made a helper method in our app, but the real solution is to either have this in the dart:html or a Pub package like you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now do that with [`ElementStream.matches`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/ElementStream.html#matches) like this :

```dart
document.body.onClick.matches('.selector').listen((Event event) {
  print('Super cool!');

  // The currently registered target for the event
  // document.body
  event.currentTarget;

  // The element whose CSS selector matched
  // .selector
  event.matchingTarget;

  // The target to which the event was originally dispatched
  // the real element clicked under .selector
  event.target;
});
```

Comment: That is interesting. How exactly does it work? What will be in the `event.target`? Imagine, that inside the `div class='selector'`, there is some `<a>Click me!</a>` element. Now there are three different elements we can be interested in: i) `body` element we are listening on (that is easy to obtain), ii) `.selector` element we are matching, iii) `<a>` element, that really received the click. Which of these will be in the `event.target`? Is it possible to obtain somehow the others?

Comment: I just maid a quick test : `e.currentTarget` points to `document.body` and `e.target` points to `<a>Click me!</a>`. I don't think you can retrieve the element matching `.selector` because there could be several `.matches` methods chained. How does jQuery handle this ?

Comment: In jQuery, `event` object passed to the handler of delegated event has three properties: `event.target` – `<a>Click me!</a>`, `event.currentTarget` – `.selector` and `event.delegatedTarget` – `document.body`, you can examine example at http://jsfiddle.net/d2fvW/ If it is not possible in Dart to obtain the equivalent of the jQuery `event.currentTarget`, it makes the delegation functionality pretty unusable:-(

Comment: There's now a [Event.matchingTarget](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Event.html#matchingTarget).

Answer (score 2):

Because I have found no viable solution, I have created package that enables delegation.

You can find it at
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/delegate

Code is simple:

```dart
delegate(parent, condition, handler) {
  return (event) {
    var element = event.target;
    while (element != parent && element != null) {
      if (condition(element)) {
        handler(event, element);
      }
      element = element.parent;
    }
  };
}

delegateOn(parent, String eventType, condition, handler) {
  parent.on[eventType].listen(delegate(parent, condition, handler));
}
```